# Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".","#","$","[",or"]". How on earth do you solve this?

Tags: javascript, java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to work with notifications from device to device and this error is driving me crazy, I don't know where I am doing wrong. I have tried everything and searched up to my best to solve this, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!
[EDIT : i had posted the question about another error here and it got solved but lead to this new error]

This is my **FirebaseMessagingClass**

```
package com.pappu5.navigation;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FirebaseMessaging extends 
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

private String channelId = "com.pappu5.navigation";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

String notificationTtile = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
String notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
String clickAction = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
String from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");


NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(this,channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(notificationTtile)
        .setContentText(notificationBody)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();


Intent intent = new Intent(clickAction);
intent.putExtra("user_id",from_user_id);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

This is Firebase **index.js** file

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotification = 

functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').
onWrite((change, context) => {

const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', 
context.params.user_id);


const fromUser = 
admin.database().ref('/Notifications/'+user_id+'/'+notification_id + 
'/From').once('value');

return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {

const from_user = fromUserResult.val();
console.log('You have new notification from : ',from_user);

const use_Query = 
admin.database().ref(`/Chat_Profiles/{from_user}/name`).once('value');

const deviceToken = 
admin.database().ref(`/Chat_Profiles/{user_id}/device_token`)
.once('value');

return Promise.all([use_Query,deviceToken]).then(result => {
const userName = result[0].val();
const token_id = result[1].val();

const payload = {
    notification: {
    title: "Friend Request",
    body: userName+" has sent you request",
    icon: "default",
    click_action : "com.pappu5.navigation_TARGET_NOTIFICATION"  
    },
    data : {
        from_user_id: from_user
    }
};
console.log(payload);
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload).then(response => {
    return console.log('This was the notification feature');
});
});


});


});
```

Comment: Please tidy up your question. Is your title an actual error message? If so, please indicate where in the 100+ lines you get it. Also, your indentation is incorrect, which makes following your code extra-hard.

Comment: yes this is the actual error message (it didnt fit in the title so i had to cut short it )

Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/Chat_Profiles/[object Object]/name". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: Error message is critical information. Title is to indicate what the post is about; but you should absolutely put the entire error message into the body of your post, and indicate on which line of code it happened in some clear way (since the numbering of the lines of code is probably different in your question and in your source code). Potential answerers are much less willing to put in the effort into answering if you don't put at least some effort into asking :) I was kind of lucky your error message (provided in comments) was verbose enough to identify the location by itself.

Answer (score 4):

In `'Chat_Profiles/'+from_user+'/name'`, `from_user` is an object. The default `toString` of an object returns `[object Object]`, which is why you get `"/Chat_Profiles/[object Object]/name"`, which is being refused. You likely wanted to use `user_id`, and not `from_user`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! well you gotta check this log http://prntscr.com/lwvake

Comment: Well i am getting the "from user id "  from this line 
const from_user = fromUserResult.val();
and its a String but why it is showing error right after the next line ?you can see the image that i posted above and why would i want "user_id "?i want the id of "from_user" so what you said doesnt fit my need also i tried doing your solution and it again the error "Values must be Strings " pops up at "data.from_user_id".I am trying to solve these from like 2 months ,i think i should give up :(

Comment: The last sentence was speculation; the rest is fact. If `user_id` is not what you want, then inspect with `console.dir` the object you have (`from_user`) and see which of its properties should stand in the path. You haven't posted that object value, so I can only guess, but probably something like `from_user.id`? The point is, the question doesn't have enough detail to give you the exact solution, only diagnose the error.

Comment: I am a complete beginner in javascript and i have posted my function log screenshot above well you can see that i can retrieve the "from_user" value and its surely a string but when i pass it is "use_Query" the error pops up. (from_user is successfully retrieved byt using console.log as seen in the screenshot)

Comment: "and its surely a string" - that looks suspiciously like an object to me. Try `'Chat_Profiles/'+from_user.From+'/name'`

Comment: Thank you for that i didnt exactly apply yours but i changed some things and got the notification in my phone also got rid of that error but again it lead it another problem and thats "user_id " is null for some reason ...latest Log Screenshot  http://prntscr.com/lxdha3   ,because of this if i click the notification the app crashes also i am not getting the icon with the notification